# Trying to install tesseract and pytesseract on mac

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract

I am trying to make a program that recognises words in images and prints them out, after looking online i found tesseract that does all the hard work for me. However when trying to use tesseract i get the following error:

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your PATH
```

I installed tesseract by using:

```
brew install tesseract
```

and i installed pytesseract by using:

```
pip3 install pytesseract
```

so i dont really understand the error. After looking online ive found some information about changing paths but again i dont understand what this means and cant find any additional information about the problem.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: I am not an expert on Mac support, but the message seems to imply that you need to put the path to tesseract into your $PATH environment variable. I think you can do that by adding it to your .profile file. I am surprised that brew did not do that.

Comment: pytesseract is python wrapper around tesseract and it expect that you installed tesseract first. Tesseract is not python project, but c++ application, so you need to use standard way (brew?) of installing it as any other application.